# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net

I use this code but can't close the connection

```
cnnstr = " Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" & CurDir() & "\datastore.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"
Dim con As New SqlConnection(cnnstr())
Dim com As New SqlCommand("insert into tblbackuphistory values('" & dateshamsi & "','" & saat & "','" & mas & "',N'" & user & "')", con)

If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then 
    con.Open() 
End If

com.ExecuteNonQuery()
com.Cancel()
com.Connection.Close()
con.Close()
com.Connection.Dispose() 
con.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 5):

If an exception is thrown by `Open()` or `ExecuteNonQuery()`, none of those `.Close()` calls that come after will ever execute. That's why you should always use a `Try/Finally` block for anything like this, and that can be shortened with a `Using` block.

While I'm here, this code is more than a little vulernable to sql injection attacks. That might be okay for a db that only exists as a local data store for an installed program (no one cares if a user wants to inject data in a database they own), but string concatenation for sql strings is still a bad habit. What happens if you end up with a user name with an apostrophe in it?

This code fixes both issues:

```vb
cnnstr = " Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" & CurDir() & "\datastore.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"

Using con As New SqlConnection(cnnstr), 
      cmd As New SqlCommand("insert into tblbackuphistory values( @dateshamsi, @saat, @mas, @user)", con)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@dateshamsi", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDatetime(dateshamsi)
    'guessing at column lengths here
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@saat", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = saat
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@mas", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = mas
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.NVarChar,50).Value = user

    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

But, based on the error from the title, this isn't the whole story. It sounds like the connection string is wrong because `datastore.mdf` file is already attached to the DB server. If you just made this DB using Sql Server Management Studio, you don't need to attach it (the `AttachDbFileName` portion). You just set the `Database=` option in the string to your database name.

Sql Server Express runs as an always-on service. It's still effectively a server-class engine, and is poorly suited as a simple local data store, even if it can work that way. It's really intended for small work groups and web sites. If you just want a local data store for you app, use Sql Server Compact, Sql Server LocalDb, SqlLite, or even MS Access.